# server responds with 400 error code for angular 11 UPDATE method

Tags: angular

Trying to update list item (labeled "Status") with value of "approved" once Approve button is clicked.

Service method for HTTP update request:

```
update(id: any, data: any): Observable<any> {
    const options = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    return this.http.put(`${this.reimbUrl}/${id}`, data, {headers: options}).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

Component method for when button is clicked:

```
approve(id: any){
    this.currentReimb = this.reimbs.find((reimb) => {return reimb.reimbId === id});
    if(this.currentReimb) {
      this.reimbService.update(id, this.currentReimb.col4status = 'Approved').subscribe(res => {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/reimbursements');
      })
    }
  }
```

HTML template code for the button:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="approve(reimb.reimbId)">Approve</button>
```

Class for the model:

```
export class Reimbursement{
    reimbId?: any;
    col1empId?: any;
    col2amount?: number;
    col3reason?: string;
    col4status?: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code 400 means that the server is expecting a different payload to this api call.

Could mean:

1. One or more properties are not correctly set (check case-sensitivity)
2. Check if you're using the correct http method (get, post, put, patch,..)
3. Check if any headers are missing
4. Check if you are able to recreate the api call inside your api-testing tool like postman, soapui, insomnia or hoppscotch

Code 400 doesn't mean that your angular code per-se is wrong, but the way you are configuring the api call to your server.

Comment: The api call inside postman worked as expected so I'm still a bit confused